# How to I show that $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{\sinh x}{x}-1\right) = \frac{1}{6}$

Tags: limits, exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

I can do this limit with a symbolic calculator and get the result.

$$\lim_{x\to0} \left[ \frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{\sinh x}{x} - 1\right) \right]  = \frac{1}{6}$$

But how would I do it by hand, and show why it is so. I know that $\lim_{x=0}\frac{\sinh(x)}{x}=1$ but that does not help here.

This is not homework, and it is related to the deflection of axially loaded beams.

Comment: Writing it as $(\sinh(x) - x)/ x^3$ and applying L'hopital three times will work, as will using the Taylor series for $\sinh(x)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT**: $$\sinh (x) = \dfrac{e^x - e^{-x}}2 = x + \dfrac{x^3}6 + \mathcal{O}(x^5)$$

Comment: Aha! Thanks. Did you even have to think about this at all? That was a quick answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can also simply use l’Hospital’s rule:

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0} \left[ \frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{\sinh x}{x} - 1\right) \right]&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sinh x-x}{x^3}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cosh x-1}{3x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sinh x}{6x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cosh x}6\\
&=\frac16\;.
\end{align*}$$